# Automatic deployment of websites and software to windows 2008 server and IIS

Tags: windows, iis

I would like to be able to script / automate the deployment / installation of a number of components to Windows server 2008. This is a single server and not part of a domain. I don't want to pay for this tool(s) if possible.

The kind of actions that i would like to be able to automate:

Required:

- Installation of .net framework and a few software packages
- Creation of directories
- Check out of .Net websites from SVN
- Check out of other file assets from SVN

Desired:
 - Creation of windows accounts
 - Setup of ISS

Anyone familiary with software that might assist me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're asking for is really an installer framework. AFAIK, there is no free tool that does all of what you want (if there is, I'd like to hear about it). You can, however, do all of this using PowerShell scripts but it isn't completely trivial.

A good starting point, if you're already familiar with PowerShell, would be the Windows Core [Management Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930): that tool is designed to do most of what you want, at least at the OS level, and it's written in powershell: you can therefore check the source code to see how various tasks are performed.

Another source you can tap is the [script center repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/). You will find pretty much all you need in the manner of sample scripts for your other tasks.

Finally, you will need to use SVN's command-line to check out your code. It's rather easy.

That's for the general point of view. In more specific instances, you can use a combination of automated OS deployment tools and continuous deployment tools to achieve the same goal (I suggest you check out the "software" section of the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) for software to try out).

Comment: Try WIX. I ran the checklist of what is reuired and I come to nothing WIX can not do.

Comment: Thanks very much - I've looked into powershell and have come up with a few solutions. Much obliged!